# Rails Devise User Exists on empty DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rake

I am trying to create a User through Devise but am running into issues.

`home#land`

```
def land
  @resource = User.new
  @devise_mapping = Devise.mappings[:user]
end
```

`land.html.haml`

```
= form_for @resource, :as => :user, :url => registration_path(:user), :remote => true do
  = label_tag 'user[email]', raw("<h3>Stay Informed!</h3>")
  = text_field_tag 'user[email]', nil, {:placeholder => "Your email", :required => true}
  %input(type="submit" name="commit" value="Add")
```

`user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation(:on => :create) do
    self.password = "none"
    self.password_confirmation = "none"
  end
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

Default Devise::RegistrationsController is being used.

This appears on submission:

`development.log`

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-24 20:49:46 -0300
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"email"=>"me@mjohnst.com"}, "commit"=>"Add"}
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'me@mjohnst.com' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  ROLLBACK
  Rendered devise/registrations/create.js (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 84ms (Views: 4.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

However, in `rails console`:

```
2.0.0p0 :011 > User.all
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

and `localhost:5000/users` is completely empty...

Why am I getting a User Exists and ROLLBACK when there are no users in my DB?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The user exists query is from the validator checking that there isn't a user with the same email you are trying to register. There is never an INSERT query, so your user is never being registered.

It is probably a validation failing. In this case your password may be too short (the default Devise password length validation requires at least a length of 8, yours is only 4).

You are receiving a successful 200 response because it is redirecting back to the registration with a flash message explaining what validations failed.

Comment: yupi...damn restriction in device.rb initializer :P thanks a lot